# What determines how high and wide the margin of a UITableView is? (see pic)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I am desperately trying to get rid of the margins around my table below:
[image]

I don't want the light gray area directly to the left and above "Brea" in the pic - I want the white table cells to extend left and up to completely cover the light grey area (to meet up with left-most white area)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has the grouped style.  You want the plain style.  If you create it programmatically, do it like this:

```
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]
                style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Or in IB, in the attributes inspector,under TableView, select Style: Plain.
[image]

Comment: Thanks - I found it - is it still possible to have the rounded edges on the table then?

Comment: @brucem yes it is, however it will be a lil bit of work. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/25/customizing-the-background-border-colors-of-a-uitableview/).

Comment: Thanks! Another option - any way to choose a custom colour for the grey area I have mentioned (instead of removing it?)

Comment: try tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

Answer (score 0):

Old topic I know, but I was able to remove the edges and use a grouped view by setting the background view to nil. Psuedo code;

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```